# SQLAlchemy - using the same join in multiple queries

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have 3 types if SQLAlchemy ORM objects A, B, and C.

I join them using a complex set of conditions.

And I have several queries where this join is used. Each of these queries has a special SELECT statement. Some of the queries also involve joining other objects.

How can I re-use this join? I don't want to use it as a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

The common join should be defined as a `sqlalchemy.orm.Query` object.

Then we can use it in all of the queries. We also should use `with_entities` in order to replace the SELECT statement with an actual one.